# Apache Shiro url-pattern matching and redirect

Tags: apache, web.xml, shiro, url-pattern

I am having trouble getting Shiro to redirect to both the login page and the desired url once logged in. This may be due to the fact that I do not have Shiro in my main web xml on the root context, but I would like to keep things separate if possible. Here's what I have so far...

```
context root: /root
```

This is the thing I want to protect access to using Shiro.

```
secondary context: /root/secondary
```

This is where I have Shiro enabled in web.xml

The way I would like this to work is when you navigate to `/root` you are redirected to `/root/secondary/login.jsp`. Then if you are able to login correctly you are directed back to `/root`. With my current configuration, I am only protecting access to `/root/secondary` and that's not my goal.

I think my question is, if the context path where Shiro is set up is `/root/secondary`, how to I have it listen for `/root`?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you are asking, it sounds like you have 2 questions: 1.) how to configure shiro in a web app, and 2.) how to protect paths? https://shiro.apache.org/web.html

Comment: Well so far I have a very basic understanding of both, but what I am trying to do is configure shiro to protect the root path while the shiro.ini is located with the secondary context in my project structure.

Comment: How are you configuring each application/context ?

Comment: Can you post your web.xml having shiro environment listener and shiro.ini file